# add a new column new_cases that computes new confirmed cases in the past week for each region

Tags: r

The problem is to Substitute "Korea, South" with "South Korea" in country_region, and then add a new column new_cases that computes new confirmed cases in the past week for each region.
If I want to calculate the past week new confirmed case, how can i write the R function with lag, could someone help me with this problem?
My code is

```
covid19_cases <- covid19 %>%
  mutate(country_region = stringr::str_replace(country_region, 
                                               "Korea, South", "South Korea"),
         new_cases = lag(confirmed, order_by = (date = "1 week")))
```

covid19_cases

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `recode` to replace the values and if you have daily data `lag` can be used with `n = 7` to get value from previous week.

```
library(dplyr)

covid19_cases <- covid19 %>%
                    mutate(country_region = recode(country_region, "Korea, South" = "South Korea")) %>%
                    group_by(country) %>%
                    mutate(new_cases = zoo::rollsumr(confirmed, 7, fill = NA))
```

Comment: I have tried that code but the question wants me to “compute new confirmed cases in the past week”, not the total number of cases 7 days ago, So may i have more hints to do this question

Comment: @wohWoh So you want to calculate sum of all the cases in past 7 days? You might need to perform rolling calculation for each country separately. See my updated answer.